# How to get DOM events triggered by jquery using observables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, observable

I am little confused,
I am using bootstrap theme in angular. Some one has written tab implementation as provided by bootstrap. But there is problem, it is in JavaScript. so events such as `bs.tab.show` are not captured by using observables. `Observable.fromEvent` does not run on subscription. The method used to trigger DOM event in bootstrap library is `$(element).trigger('bs.tab.show', ...)` 
My basic understanding is whenever any event such as click, hover or in my case `bs.tab.show` is triggered from DOM, event goes in event stack, and observables is using same event stack to read events.
Could anyone point out difference?

Comment: Can you please create a StackBlitz that reproduces the problem, and shows the code you've tried? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have the name of the events wrong.

If I use `fromEvent` with `show.bs.tab` instead, the event is triggered.

```
fromEvent(elem, 'show.bs.tab').subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Heard")
})
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhysfh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi i have forked your demo. Which is the way i am trying to do. Please follow below link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2d5to?file=src/app/app.component.ts. it's not working. I am trying to get element using @Viewmodel.

Comment: It appears you'll need to use jQuery to get the elements seeing as the event is not a standard DOM event. Try `fromEvent($('[role="tab"]'), 'show.bs.tab')`

Comment: Thanks @user184994 i can get the event by getting element using jquery. but could you tell me why it is necessary to use jQuery. As it is an event it must be going through event pool and observable must pick the event from it. Could you please tell me what wrong here?